# Exception "The target principal name is incorrect" on long-running Azure Web role

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've got an Azure Web role that has developed a problem in the last few days. Without changing anything or re-deploying the role or the database, the Web role lost the ability to connect to its database. It throws this exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) 

at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) 
...
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) 
...
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

Restarting the Web role or the role's VM has no effect. Republishing the Web role via Web Deploy, even without making changes, stops the problem from occurring for a while, sometimes as long as a day.

I'm going to redeploy the entire package to see if that helps.

The only thing that I can see might be an issue is that we use a DNS alias for the SQL Database server. Instead of "abcd4567.database.windows.net" for the connection string, we use "our.fqdn.com".

Again, though, the Web role performs perfectly and makes all kinds of database connections...until it stops.

We're not hitting a throttle, either, because the database in question isn't heavily used, maybe a few dozen connections per hour.

Any diagnostic ideas would be helpful.

Comment: The problem seems to have resolved itself. So Adam was probably right (duplicate DNS entries) but it was Microsoft's dodgy DNS that they fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This error is sometimes caused by duplicate DNS entries. Have you added an identical DNS entry to your domain recently?

You can test that this is the cause by changing your application to use "abcd4567.database.windows.net"

Comment: We can take a look at that, but the domain is an Azure directory. This is an Azure Web role talking to an Azure database. If it persists, we might go back to the Azure FQDNs

Comment: This was my issue! Thanks, @adam. Check DNS entries: `nslookup abcd4567`

Answer (score 0):

When generating DBContext using the Scaffolding, if you are getting the error while connection "provider ssl provider error 0 - the target principal name is incorrect"
use this parameter for the connection string: **TrustServerCertificate=true**

AS the server connection is based on the certificate errors.